# Why my code had this error

Tags: java

Console error: When I enter 1 letter

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 1  at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown
>   Source)   at javaB.Cipher.main(Cipher.java:17)

```
package javaB;
import java.util.*;

public class Cipher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);
        String key1="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwkyz ";
        String key2="QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM_";
        System.out.println("System launched----enter the code----");
        String aw=reader.nextLine();

        for(int ii=0;ii<=aw.length();ii++)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<=27;i++)
            {
                if(aw.charAt(i)==key1.charAt(i))
                {
                    System.out.println(key2.charAt(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because `aw` is shorter than 28 characters

Comment: Probably because `aw` is shorter than 2 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the i =1, as java is zero index based aw.charAt(1) tries to get the second char from aw. As aw ="Q" and it has single character the following line of code  will throw StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
aw.charAt(i)==key1.charAt(i)
```

Looks like you wanted to write the code to compare aw.charAt(ii) with key1.charAt(i)

```
aw.charAt(ii) == key1.charAt(i)
```

Check this out.

Comment: Your are Welcome. Feel free to uptick the answer or mark it correct.

Answer (score 1):

In both of your `for` loops you are using the `<=` operator which means that you accessing index beyond the end of your `key..` arrays. Use the `<` operator. In other words from 0 to 27 inclusive there are 28 numbers, you need to exclude the 27th index.